# SQL Server: Retrieve auto-incremented ID inside a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, auto-increment

My database has a parent table with an auto-incrementing primary key identity 'ID', and a normal 'TIMESTAMP column'. I have child tables with a foreign key that refer to the parent 'ID' column.

I want to write a stored procedure that inserts a new column into both the parent and child databases. How would I set the child 'ID' column to equal the new auto-incremented parent 'ID' column? Does this require a separate:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM PARENT_TABLE
```

Or is there another way?

Comment: If you end up using the SCOPE_IDENTITY, make sure you read the remarks in the documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315(SQL.90).aspx); especially if you have a trigger on the table you're inserting into.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can retrieve it from SCOPE_IDENTITY().  For example:

```
declare @myid int
INSERT INTO table (field) VALUES ('value')
SELECT @myid = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Answer (score 1):

select scope_identity();