# How to get a Auto generate number in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I am making a Inventory Software . In that i need to make a auto generated item code so that the users can use that code to pick that item. I would like to know how to make such colum and whats the best way to do it.

i need to start the itemcode from "1000"

For example i have the following columns in my table

```
ItemID int
ItemCode 
ItemName
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto number fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670020/auto-number-fields)

Comment: A similar question on SO [retrieve SQL Server auto increment id inside a stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/831810/sql-server-retrieve-auto-incremented-id-inside-a-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the GUID or the Autoincrement column is not enough for your business you have to create a Function to auto generate  your custom code

have a look at the below:

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/custom-auto-generated-sequences-with-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

Would you please try wit below way:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TargetTableName](
    [ItemID ] [int] IDENTITY(1000,1) NOT NULL,
    [ItemCode] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ItemName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT [PK_TargetTableName] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [ItemID ] ASC
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [Identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) column and seed it to start at 1000.

You may however wish to consider writing some business logic to generate a meaningful code, I always consider it slightly bad practise to use an Identity column for a data item which has meaning to your users. It's generally used to generate non-meaningful table primary keys. It is possible (although admittedly unlikely) to force SQL Server to regenerate the same value for an Identity column (for example if the table is ever truncated).

Answer (score 0):

```
Create procedure [dbo].[randomnum]     --exec  [randomnum] '1000','9999',''
(                                     --Set Minimun and Maximum value
@min bigint,               
@max bigint,  
@nvarrs bigint output  

)  

AS Declare  
@nvarrc bigint,  
@num bigint   

set @nvarrc = @max  
set @nvarrs =@min - 1  

while @nvarrs < @min  
Begin  
set @nvarrs = (ceiling(rand() * @nvarrc))  
  Select @nvarrs RandomNumber
End
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I saw this recommended somewhere and I am using it: Pretty cool!
http://generatedata.com/